# How can I detect fast and slow motion in videos?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, long-short-term-memory, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to detect if a given video shot is fast or slow motion. Basically, I need to calculate a "video motion" score in a given video sequence, meaning how fast or slow motion the video is. For instance, if a video is about a car racing or camera moving fast, the score is high. Whereas if the video is about two persons standing/talking, then the motion is low, so the lower score.

What comes into my mind is using **optical flow** which is already an implemented function in OpenCV. I never used it. But I don't know how to interpret or use it for a "motion score".

Is optical flow applicable here? How can I use it to calculate a score? In particular, if there is a ML/Deep learning model that already does it, please share it.